# Convergence of $\sum \sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I show the series converges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$

Hint is that use comparison test but not many inequalities come to mind.

Comment: Hint : $|\sin (x)|\le |x|$ for all $x$, and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$
\sin x \leq x
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}_+$, along with the fact that $\sin$ is odd:
$$
\lvert \sin x\rvert \leq \lvert x\rvert.
$$

Than, a comparison with the "right" $p$-series will do the trick.

Comment: Maybe you mean $\sin x \leq x$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$.

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729 Indeed, forgot the $+$ in the subscript. Fixed, thank you.